# Oracle listener port

Tags: oracle, listener

I'm using Oracle 12c Enterprise Edition. I have something strange in the configuration of listener.

1. Check listener if it is running

```
$ ps -ef | grep tns
root        261      2  0 Jan16 ?        00:00:00 [netns]
oraxxx    12669      1  0 Jan16 ?        00:10:33 /oracle/PR1/112_64/bin/tnslsnr LISTENER -inherit
```

2. Check status of listener LISTENER, we can see it listens on port 9119

```
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/grid/12.1.0.1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/xxx/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=LISTENER)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.x.x.x)(PORT=9119)))
```

3. Check content of listener file. I cannot find the port 9119 configured here.

```
$ cat /u01/app/grid/12.1.0.1/network/admin/listener.ora

LISTENER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=LISTENER))))            # line added by Agent
ENABLE_GLOBAL_DYNAMIC_ENDPOINT_LISTENER=ON              # line added by Agent
VALID_NODE_CHECKING_REGISTRATION_LISTENER=SUBNET                # line added by Agent
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
(SID_LIST =
        (SID_DESC =
                (GLOBAL_DBNAME = xxx_DG)
                (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.1/db_1)
                (SID_NAME = xxx)
        )
)
```

--> How can Oracle know it will run on port 9119 if no port configured in the listener.ora?

4. Check the local_listener and nothing is shown

```
SYS@xxx> show parameter local_listener;

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
local_listener                       string
```

In my test server, I can see the port configured in the listener.ora file and value in the local_listener

```
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.56.103)(PORT = 1901))

SQL> show parameter local_listener

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
local_listener                       string      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP) (HOST=
                                                 192.168.56.103) (PORT=1901))
```

I wonder if there is any special configuration that I may not know or hear. Can someone advise me on this case.

Comment: Notice the directory `....12.1.0.1` while you're using version `11g` and directory `/oracle/PR1/112_64....`. Perhaps you have a mismatch due to this.

Comment: I double check on this, as this is my mistake. I open 2 different systems to check this. One of them is 11g. The version is 12c, I have updated the post.

Comment: If not ports are configured, then it is 1521. You have listener running from the 11g home (or so it seems from the name of the file path), and you're checking one that is running from a 12c home. Do you have RAC configured? if yes, check the configuration using 'srvctl config listener'.

Comment: Look like it the old path and oracle is upgraded to 12c later. It's not default port 1521. As seen above, it's 9119. It's not RAC.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on tnsnames.ora

```
LISTENER_xxx_DG =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (PROTOCOL = TCP)
    (HOST = xxx-DG)
    (PORT = 9119)
  )
```

So, the listener code can be included in the tnsnames.ora?